# Unable to authenticate to http API when using public url from same machine (Kestrel/.NET7)

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, windows-authentication, dotnet-httpclient, kestrel-http-server

I have a .NET7 service which is running kestrel to host an http API (REST controller). The service uses windows authentication with a local windows account. There is an SSL certificate installed and the service is running on a Windows VM in Azure.

When I access the service using a browser or httpClient from my home PC everything works great. e.g. https://blah.myservice.com:21000/api/foo - this challenges me for credentials, I put them in and it returns data and the browser is happy with the SSL cert.

When I access the service in the same way from another Azure VM on the same network it also works as expected.

The issue is that when I access the public URL from the same machine that the service is running on I get a 401 unauthorized response from the service.

If I do https://localhost:21000/api/foo then it challenges me for credentials and returns data just fine, but the browser is not happy with the SSL cert because the domain in the browser does not match. That's not a mystery, obviously. But the service does work. It also works using the local network IP address of the machine.

I don't understand why I get a 401 when using the public URL - it's hitting the right service because I can see the request come in through the log files, it just won't authenticate after challenging me.

The reason this bothers me is that I have a number of services running on a few VMs - sometimes they take data from each other which means they have to effectively connect to localhost to call the REST controllers on another service. This will fail with a 401 if I use the public URL, but will also fail if I use "localhost" because the certificate does not validate. e.g. this code fails when going from one service to another on the same host (or just running it as a console app on the same server):

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

var httpClientHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler { Credentials = credentials };
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler, true);

try
{
   string result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://blah.myservice.com:21000/api/foo");
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

try
{
   string result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:21000/api/foo");
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Both of the above requests fail - I realise I can set the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback to always return true but that's a hack and I have a valid SSL cert so it makes no sense to do that.

Is anyone able to explain why this doesn't work and how to fix it?